# Convert Client-Server Application to Web connection: REST or Client side query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, delphi, https

I have written some applications in Delphi for a production company, the purpose of this application is label printing and production data acquisition.All of these applications are Client-Server (Using ZeosLib connecting directly to PostgreSQL through 5432 port).

In recent days, the company has acquired other production sites and wants to install my software in these sites. It's not possible to make a LAN2LAN connection, and the only way to communicate from external production sites to corporate headquarters is via HTTP (https) server through internet connection.

When I was presented with the problem, the first thing I thought was to convert applications to use REST and write all server side queries making calls to the right endpoints. However, this requires a lot of work: applications have many queries to rewrite.

Therefore, for time reasons, I tried to create a server side PHP script capable of receiving requests written in SQL, connecting to PostgreSQL and responding in JSON data. After that, I have modified my application extending ZeosLib connections with an additional protocol (named websql) able to redirect SQL queries to the PHP script and convert the received JSON data to Delphi DataSet compliant format.

Everything works fine: in all my applications I can now change the connection protocol with the new "websql", and I could quickly install the new versions in the branch offices.

Doing this test was very simple, but now there is a security problem: The Web connection is protected by user/password and by https, but is it still sufficient?
Should a client application be allowed to send queries via https? Before installing the applications in production I would like to know if there is a way to make this architecture as secure as possible or if it is appropriate to rewrite all the applications with REST communication.

Thank you all,

Andrea

Comment: If you want more securiy, the server can check the client IP (via a white list). Or, as fpiette suggested, you could use client certificates, but it requires more work to set up.

Comment: Another thing to consider: your app will be dependent on an Internet connection. If the connection isn't available for some time, isn't it problematic for your "production data acquisition"? Why not use a local PostgreSQL database?

Comment: Hi Oliver, the main system data change frequently and must be updated every time a new label is created...so i need to obtain and send information to main PostgreSQL database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Providing a JSON gateway to run SQL from the client side is not proper REST, and should not be used for any serious work.

Several Reasons:

1. Anyone on the client side with the credentials could run any kind of SQL statements, which may be pretty unsafe, like DROP TABLE or DROP DATABASE in the middle of a SELECT statement. Or it could access data from other customers.
2. You still have the logic on the Client side. This is not n-Tier, this is 2-Tier in disguise. The fact that you use HTTPS+JSON instead of direct connection to the DB doesn't change the global architecture.
3. HTTPS is safe only if both sides (client and server) forces their certificates for mutual authentication. Otherwise, MiM attacks are very common. Using a VPN or a SSH tunnel may help.
4. Performance may not be very good, since you don't cache the data, and network latency is worse over the Internet than over a local network.
5. If you really want to go this direction, don't reinvent the wheel, and use a more tuned solution like our [Open Source SynDBRemote](https://github.com/synopse/mORMot/blob/master/SynDBRemote.pas) which works very well with Zeos/ZDBC - or [proprietary alternatives](https://www.tmssoftware.com/site/remotedb.asp).

But I would rather switch to a REST architecture, with the logic on the server side, and the SQL on this server side. It will be easier to maintain and scale, and allow non Delphi clients - e.g. JavaScript clients on Desktop or Mobile.

Comment: The OP said VPN or SSH can't be used: only HTTPS can be used thru internet connection. Both VPN and SSH will be really secure when certificates are used. At client side certificate could be omitted when a digipass (hardware device) with pin code is used.

Comment: Thanks, verifying the points you indicated led me to further considerations. I agree in general, I have made this question because this is a serious application and I want to make the right choice, but these are also company-specific applications and we must use a limited user logged to PostgreSQL (to prevent DROP TABLE etc..).
For the client side we have made our "websql" protocol because we also use Lazarus sqlDb (We have also WinCE 6.0 Terminals) Zeos is not compatible with WinCE so we have created the websql connection for ZeosLib and sqlDB from scratch.

Comment: Maybe in the first step we will install software in this way with both-side certificates (as also suggested by @fpiette) then one-by-one we will convert all applications in REST (in agreement with the master company).

Answer (score 1):

HTTPS is enough and secure provided you use certificates at both sides and obviously check for certificate validity.

When using a certificate, a client is sure to connect to the server he think to connect to or he gets a certificate error. Same for server: when a client use a certificate, the server can be sure the client is a legitimate client.

Comment: Hi fpiette, thank you. In fact, my question is for understand if the security level is guaranteed in relation to the fact that the client can launch SQL (Using a TZQuery component) via an https connection, if can be accepted for this kind of applications ... in my company there was a debate about that :)

Comment: HTTPS with certificate is not the same as HTTPS without certificate! As I said, using certificate, each part is assured that the other part is the one which it pretend to be. That's a really high security. This prevent "man in the middle" attack.

Comment: And by the way, please mark my answer as "accepted" (The tick mark) if you find it the correct answer to your question.

Comment: HTTPS with server-side certificates can be compromised, and is compromised in almost all big companies. Those IT infrastructure usually use a Proxy, and register their own root certificate on each PC of the company. So everything is uncrypted, inspected, and re-encrypted in the IT proxy server.

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez Those proxies are not a problem. The OP want to protection between external production sites to corporate headquarters and HTTPS with certificate provides the required protection. And obviously the company having such proxy trust their system and make the proxy validate certificates.

Comment: Handling certificates on both client and server sides is a practical nightmare. For safety reasons, you need to regenerate them often, and most of the time, clients complain that "it does not work" because their certificate is outdated. And the more clients, the more certificates on the server side, unless you sign the client certificates with a root certificate of your own, then your system is just as secure as this root certificate is secure. I have never liked this mutual solution in practice. Just my two cents.

Comment: Managing certificates complexity depends on the software used. And if you write your own software with Delphi, your are free to spend more time developing software and less time managing. Or the reverse...